# Python MySQL insert into with parameter

Tags: python, mysql

I am having a hard time using the MySQLdb module to insert information into my database. I need to insert 2 variables into the table.My table is userid,the type of user_id is **varchar**,the type of count is **int**.

```
  SQL = 'select user_id,count(*)AS num from client1 group by user_id order by count(*) desc;'
  for row in cursor.execute(SQL):
       a = row.user_id
       b = row.num
       cursormysql.execute("insert into userid(user_id,count) VALUES (%s,%s))",(a,b))
       db.commit()
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code and the error as text, rather than images. Imagine the one person who is able to help you is **very** busy and won't bother waiting for images to load to answer a question.

Answer (score 1):

Your parenthesis do not match on 
`cursormysql.execute("insert into userid(user_id,count) VALUES (%s,%s))",(a,b))`

Try like `cursormysql.execute("insert into userid(user_id,count) VALUES (%s,%s)",(a,b))`

Comment: `) `right before double quotes see my updated answer